# Infinite runner has bumps. How do I smooth it?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-physics

I have a script that spawns my ground prefabs infinitely. The only problem is that occasionally there is a "bump" for the player to hit at the boundary of a new ground prefab.

It seems like one prefab is slightly higher than the previous one and when the player hits that small bump they go flying. How do I fix this?

I might just make the player a game object instead of a rigidbody and animate it instead of using actual physics.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class GroundManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    //oH is object height

    public GameObject[] ground;
    public GameObject[] obstacles;
    private Transform playerTransform;
    private float spawnZ = 0.0f;
    private float spawnO = 0.0f;
    public float oH;
    private float tileLength = 40.0f;
    private float oLength = 36.0f;
    private int tilesOnScreen = 8;


    void Start()
    {
        playerTransform = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Player").transform;



        for (int i = 0; i < tilesOnScreen; i++)
        {
            SpawnTile();
            SpawnObstacle();
        }




    }

    // Player must be tagged "Player"
    void Update()
    {
        if (playerTransform.position.z > (spawnZ - tilesOnScreen * tileLength))
        {
            SpawnTile();
            SpawnObstacle();
        }

    }

    private void SpawnTile(int prefabIndex = -1)
    {
        GameObject go;
        go = Instantiate(ground[0]) as GameObject;
        go.transform.SetParent(transform);
        go.transform.position = Vector3.forward * spawnZ;
        spawnZ += tileLength;
    }

    private void SpawnObstacle()
    {

        GameObject go;
        go = Instantiate(obstacles[Random.Range(0, obstacles.Length)]) as GameObject;
        go.transform.SetParent(transform);
        go.transform.position = new Vector3(0, oH, 1 * spawnO);
        spawnO += oLength;
    }


}
```

This code works to infinitely spawn the ground objects but has the bumps that I described. Just one bump is enough to screw up the whole game.

Comment: yeah definitely you dont need rigidbody for a infinite runner.

Comment: If I want to make a car drift and hit ramps will I need a rigidbody?

Comment: you never really "need" it. Can make it work both ways.

Comment: I think I want to make the body of the car a rigidbody and the wheels gameobjects, then I need the body of the car to float in space instead of being supported by the wheels. I haven't found a way to achieve this. This way the car will move using physics but the wheels won't hit the edge of the ground when it spawns.

Comment: Adding a rigid body to the car but using game object movement to move it seems to solve the colliding with the ground problem. How do I make the car have awesome wipe out physics?